# python: use strptime() for object that is not zero padding

Tags: python, timestamp, time-series, data-mining, data-cleaning

I have a pandas data frame that has two columns both of them in object format. They contain year (4 means 2004) and month. I want to subtract them.

```
start     end
4-oct     12-nov
dec-3     11-oct
jan-5     16-dec
12-oct    17-apr
```

I tried:

```
data['end'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(repr(x), "'%y-%b'"))
data['end'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(repr(x), "b'%y-%b'"))
```

But they did not work.

1. How can I deal with the different format and **non zero padding** in the first column ('%y-%b' and '%b-%y')
2. How can I apply strptime() to object format? (can repr() convert them to string)?

Comment: Is `des-3` a typo or a language issue?

Comment: First, why are you using `%y-%b`? `%y` means year, not day. Second, why are you trying to parse the string repr (in the first example) and bytes repr (in the second) instead of just parsing the string itself`, strptime(x, fmt)`?

Comment: They are years for example 3 means 2003.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your code.

- You're using `%y`, which requires a 2-digit year, but some of your years are 1-digit. Fortunately, those only appear in `start`, and you're only asking how to parse `end`. But if you want to parse `start` as well—or if your real data have single-digit years, you'd need to fix this.
- You're calling `repr` on the string, and then trying to parse the string repr, instead of just parsing the string. (Your strings are already strings. `object` is the base class of every type in Python, including `str`. And that's what Pandas uses for a Series that doesn't have a nice type it knows how to deal with, like int64 or datetime64—it just stores the native Python objects with whatever native Python type they have, like `str`.)
- Some of your strings are in month-year format instead of year-month, so the same format string obviously isn't going to parse them. You'll need to either use some kind of heuristic parser (maybe from `dateutil`), or preprocess them all into the same format, or write a function that tries both formats.
- One of your strings doesn't even have a valid month. You can't parse `des-3` as a month and year, because `des` is not a month. I'm not sure what you want to do about that. Maybe use a not-a-date value?
- Apply doesn't mutate the `DataFrame` in-place, it just returns a new `Series` that you have to store somewhere.

Putting it all together:

```
def parsedate(s):
    try:
        return datetime.strptime(s, '%y-%b')
    except ValueError:
        pass
    try:
        return datetime.strptime(s, '%b-%y')
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return datetime.now() # <whatever you actually want to do for des-3 here>
df.end = df.end.apply(parsedate)
```

This will work, and give you `Timestamp` values that you can subtract from each other to get `Timedelta` values.

And of course it'll turn `des-3` into `now()`, which probably isn't what you want; you have to decide what you actually want.

---

Since your format is such a mess, instead of trying to cram it into something approaching a standard format and then deal with a bunch of error handling, it may be better to just parse it manually with code designed for your idiosyncratic format. Something like this:

```
MONTHS = {
    'jan': 1, 'feb': 2, 'mar': 3, 'apr': 4, 'may': 5, 'jun': 6,
    'jul': 7, 'aug': 8, 'sep': 9, 'oct': 10, 'nov': 11, 'dec': 12, 'des': 12 }
def parsedate(s):
    part1, _, part2 = s.partition('-')
    if part2.isdigit():
        part1, part2 = part2, part1
    return datetime(year=2000+int(part1), month=MONTHS[part2], day=1)
```

Comment: @Juang My answer shows how to parse them as years, so what's the point of this comment?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `%y-%b` directly rather than on the repr:

```
In [11]: df['end'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%y-%b"))
Out[11]:
0   2012-11-01
1   2011-10-01
2   2016-12-01
3   2017-04-01
Name: end, dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [12]: pd.to_datetime(df["end"], format="%y-%b")  # alternatively/more efficient
Out[12]:
0   2012-11-01
1   2011-10-01
2   2016-12-01
3   2017-04-01
Name: end, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Once they are both in pandas datetime64 Series, you can subtract them with `-`.

---

To fix the single digit year (in the start column) I'd use a regex to normalize them:

```
In [21]: df["start"].replace({"^(\d-.*)$": "0\\g<1>", "^(.*)-(\d)$": "0\\g<2>-\\g<1>"}, regex=True)
Out[21]:
0    04-oct
1    03-dec
2    05-jan
3    12-oct
Name: start, dtype: object
```

Then you can apply the format above.

Comment: `%M` means minutes. Why would you use that?

Comment: They are all years, for example, 4-oct means 2004 October. jan-5 means 2005 January.

Comment: @abarnert ah, it was a copy and paste

Comment: @AndyHayden OK, so why do you _still_ have `%M` in your answer?

Comment: @abarnert sorry, I had intended to come back to this. Added a regex based solution. Although I guess I still don't understand OP's question 2.